# How to solve this problem solving question?

Tags: problem-solving

I probably look like a complete idiot asking this question, but how do you solve these two questions about calculating the perimeter of these circles.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint (for [Pac-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man#/media/File:Pacman-cutscene.png)): circumference is $80 \,\pi\,$, then deduct $\frac{40^\circ}{360^\circ}=\frac{1}{9}$ of it, then add twice the radius.